# Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type '{ length: 3; }'

Tags: typescript

I've wrote the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAHgXBDeEA2BTAdgcwC4As4GYIBfCAXggCIQAjAYwoG4BYAKCA):

```
var x: { length: 3 } = "abc";
```

and it fails to compile with message

> Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type '{ length: 3; }'.

But the string `abc` definitely has length equal to 3. What's wrong?

---

> `"abc"` is a `string` and `{ length: 3 }` is an object with a `length` property that must equal the number 3, they don't intersect at all.

But [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAngXBDeEA2BTAdgcwC4As5oFcBbAIxUgF8IBeCAIhBIGM6BuAWACgg) is valid:

```
var y: { length: number } = "abc";
```

So seems like there is no problem with an object?

Comment: There's no way to specify a string length with typescript. What you are doing here is creating an object literal and setting it equal to something. Not valid code.

Comment: `"abc"` is a `string` and `{ length: 3 }` is an object with a `length` property that must equal the number `3`, they don't intersect at all.

Comment: @Rager, why? Also it works fine with `{ length: number }`.

Comment: @Marty, but `{ length: number }` is valid.

Comment: The type for `string` is `length: number` not `length: 3`, so they types for length essential don't overlap anymore if you specify `3` instead.

Comment: @Marty, so `length` is properly inferred only for tuples, but not for strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently know anything about the `length` property of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) more specific than the fact that it's a `number`.  Nor does it know anything about the type of any character of the a string literal more specific than the fact that it will be a `string`.  At runtime, `"abc".length` will be `3`, but all the compiler knows is that it's `number`.  At runtime, `"abc"[1]` will be `"b"`, but all the compiler knows is that it's `string`.

There is an [open issue, microsoft/TypeScript#34692,](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692) which suggests that such narrowings happen automatically for string literals.  If you want to see this happen, you might want to go there and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's particularly compelling.

If, for some reason, you need more specific typings for a particular string literal, you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to manually inform the compiler of your expectations, such as the following:

```
const x = "abc" as StringLiteral<"abc", ["a", "b", "c"]>;

const len = x.length; // const len: 3
console.log(len); // 3

const b = x.charAt(1).charAt(0)[0][0] // const b: StringLiteral<"b",["b"]>
console.log(b); // "b"
```

where my `StringLiteral` type is defined like

```
type StrToNum = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
type Rev<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof any>> = {
    [K in T[keyof T]]: { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends K ? P : never }[keyof T]
};
type NumToStr = Rev<Pick<StrToNum, Exclude<keyof StrToNum, keyof any[]>>>;
type StringLiteral<T extends string, A extends string[] = [T]> =
    { [K in "length" | Exclude<keyof A, keyof any[]>]:
        A[K] extends string ? StringLiteral<A[K], [A[K]]> : A[K] } & {
            charAt<N extends keyof NumToStr>(
                pos: N
            ): StringLiteral<Extract<A[Extract<NumToStr[N], keyof A>], string>>
        } & T;
```

But I can't imagine it's worth the effort.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-asG74PhUBoeaVkYLSLKgUkQ5lxsbwgt9N5HAioLYUuSYgAjTwMmLuSMqmNQ5tt8la5uDiktkfk9tfBZQGvIOvAKBUwp4WwAOiXNNpWigAHod1Ba-Wl1UaLO68gqevkICPUvQ9u91BT3oz-WWyk15brbaPWRQ6uvxtYAPUIUMiA0cDd33Q8FxbCNMSjVU+zHYh8HJMcvlfC8ICvG8W3vKDR3JfQgA)